# How to run automatically php script very 24 hours based on timestamp from table in php

Tags: javascript, php, database

anyone can help me, i want run script very 24 hours based on timestamp from table in php

Am making investment website. i want add interest rate add daily to user database, actually i want run that script every 24 hours, i used cronjob but its not working perfectly because some users maybe time different with approx 10 seconds or 2 seconds. in cronjob there is possible with every secon only have every minute   option

```
$d_test2  + 86400 <= $timestamp
```

**$d_test2** is *timestamp* from database

```
$timestamp = time();
```

how can solve this is issue?

i want add daily interest rate based on user timestamp

Comment: You can set cronjob with option years to second run you have to set relevant parameters for that.

Answer (score 0):

You will need something called cron jobs in PHP

Try ging through this link

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/schedule-cron-jobs-in-php/

Comment: i tried with cronjob its working the problem if 14766888 from table database , but cronjob execute before or after the program wont execute na, that is only problem

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand you. Could you reframe that?

Comment: $d_test2 = 14766888 this is from user database the program need to run after 24 hours that means 14766888+86400, if i use cronjob every minute if cron execution and $d)test2 value different means the program won't execute na

Comment: $d_test2 =14766888 + 86400 = 14853288 if cron execute after 1 seconds or before  1 seconds

Comment: I didn't quite get it but use modulus i.e. %60 to get the fractional value and subtract it.